# Copy over existing files without confirmation?

Tags: linux, centos, cp

I need to copy and over-write a large amount of files, I've used the following command:

```
# cp -Rf * ../
```

But then whenever a file with the same name exists on the destination folder I get this question:

```
cp: overwrite `../ibdata1'?
```

The Problem is that I have about 200 files which are going to be over-written and I don't think that pressing `Y then Enter` 200 times is the right way to do it.

So, what is the right way to that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You do realise that RHEL and CentOS have tried to protect novice users by setting up aliases for the root user to prevent accidentally overwriting and deleting files?

```
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

The `-i` switch is what requires confirmation when modifying or removing existing files. Because alias expansion happens before execution of the command even the use of the `--force -f`  switch will still require confirmation.

You can remove the alias permanently by editing the `/root/.bashrc` file, remove the alias for the duration of a session with `unalias cp`  or for a single command use one of:

- use the full path `/bin/cp`
- use quotes `"cp"` or `'cp'` around the command
- use the command keyword e.g. `command cp`
- escape the command `\cp`

Answer (score 59):

You can do `yes | cp -rf myxx`, Or if you do it as root - your .bashrc or .profile has an alias of cp to cp -i, most modern systems do that to root profiles.

You can temporarily bypass an alias and use the non-aliased version of a command by prefixing it with \, e.g. \cp whatever

Comment: +1 for pointing at how to bypass an alias. Tempted to -1 for the brute force solution.

Comment: +! for the `yes` pipe function - very handy!

Comment: what does -rpf do? I have seen it used multiple times in scripts.